# How to see the uncompressed size before unpacking

Tags: c#, vb.net, zip, gzip, dotnetzip

I am using DotNetZip to extract zip files that come from an extenal (not trustworthy) source. My problem is that the zip file itself can be a couple of kilobytes, but the unzipped content can become petabytes. How to see the uncompressed size before unpacking? Is there a reliable way to see this and prevent a OutOfMemoryException?

As suggested below it can be done with ionic zip:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFile))
                {
                 // Option 2 - will need to sift through the mass of info

                 info = zip.Info;

foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
                    {
                        long uncompressedsize = e.UncompressedSize;
                        // Option 1
                        totaluncompressedsize += uncompressedsize;
                    }
                 }
```

But the question remains: Is the `UncompressedSize` completely reliable? Can someone change this information to make it appear as a small uncompressed size?

Comment: Hmya, this is a lot like bringing a knife to a gun-fight.  You really do need to have a Big Guy at the door that stops people with guns from entering the building.  That guy can only make the right call if he knows who's asking to enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not *completely* reliable.  The uncompressed size in a zip file can certainly be altered by a malicious source.  You should use the uncompressed size to limit the memory used, and if the decompression goes past that, simply stop and reject the zip file.  You should never rely on the input to avoid exceptions.

It is possible to decode a compressed entry and determine its uncompressed size without actually generating the uncompressed output.  However there's not much point to that if you're going to decompress anyway.  Decoding takes almost as long as decompressing.  Just start decompressing and stop when you hit the claimed uncompressed size.

Comment: Now that is a great answer. I will just limit the byte array length according to the uncompressed size. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[How to find uncompressed size of ionic zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944831/how-to-find-uncompressed-size-of-ionic-zip-file) Is a similar question which might help you.
Basically you iterate over each Entry and add the uncompressed size up.

Comment: +1 for correct link... Also it should be duplicate (which you probably don't yet have permission to suggest).